# Certificate for Exchange 2010 exports to binary

Tags: windows, exchange-2010, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to renew our exchange 2010 certificate. I have followed [this guide](http://www.stephenwagner.com/?p=435).  When I try to open the `.req` file it is in binary.

Is there a way to convert it to text so I can continue with the guide?

Comment: Do you plan on using an internal CA, or do you need to enroll your request with a public CA (like VeriSign, Comodo, GoDaddy, etc.?)

Comment: Hi, I plan to use an Internal CA on another server rather than self certificate or use VeriSign etc. Thank you for the solution below, I will try this later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this in the GUI (the Exchange Management Console) before.

To resolve this, I used the Exchange Management Shell instead:

First, find the thumbprint of the certificate you are about to renew, by issuing:

```
Get-ExchangeCertificate
```

Copy the Thumbprint and generate a CSR by piping it to the `New-ExchangeCertificate` cmdlet:

```
Get-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbprint "The Thumbprint goes here" | New-ExchangeCertificate -GenerateRequest -KeySize 2048 -PrivateKeyExportable:$true
```

Comment: Hi. This was helpful, but when I created a new certificate and renewed the certificate, the Expiration date was the same. Do you have any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to open the Certificates MMC, and simply right-click the certificate and choose "Renew with new key". It should let you choose a domain CA to enroll your request with, right away

Comment: I have done this, The main CA needed updating also. Thank you for your help.